# How to get Cilk working with Cygwin?

Tags: c, cygwin, cilk, cilk-plus

I have downloaded both programs, but I see no instructions on google for getting Cilk to work on Cygwin.  Is there a Cygwin package that would work?  I'm programming in C and have gcc installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it from source.

That will link the `cygwin32.dll` with the binaries which are essential for it to work with cygwin.

Here is a guide: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/sct/wiki/index.php?title=Cilk_Plus_Installation_Guide to build it from source with `gcc`.